# Storing and Retrieving PDF Files in Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance, varbinarymax

I use Azure SQL Managed Instance as DB and ADLS for file storage. Now the requirement is to store few small PDF files (about 200 kb each). Storing and retrieving will be done through .NET.

Which is the best and easiest approach?

1. Storing the PDFs in database as `VARBINARY(max)` column.
2. Storing the PDFs in ADLS.

Comment: What about Azure Blob Storage? (while ADLS is related to Blob Storage, it's intended for "big data" analytics systems, not for file storage - and, I don't see how the extra features would be a benefit here...

Comment: ADLS Gen 2 is simply the Hierarchical Namespace feature of Azure Blob storage.  You can use both the BLOB API and the ADLS API on the storage account.  With ADLS already in the solution it's probably not worth adding a separate storage account.  Also enabling "Hierarchical Namespace" is required for NFS and SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the best and easiest approach?

Since you're already using ADLS it's the best *and* easiest approach for file storage for your application.